# How to send a gcm xmpp message with Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration and to Google Cloud Message. `XmppConnectionFactoryBean` is created successfully and I can autowire a `XmppConnection` in my service class.

```
@Configuration
class XmppConfig {

    @Value("${gcm.sender_id}")
    private String senderId;

    @Value("${gcm.api_key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Value("${gcm.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${gcm.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration() {
        ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host, port);
        connectionConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
        connectionConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
        connectionConfig.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
        connectionConfig.setSendPresence(false);
        connectionConfig.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

        return connectionConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public XmppConnectionFactoryBean xmppConnectionFactoryBean() {
        XmppConnectionFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean = new XmppConnectionFactoryBean();
        connectionFactoryBean.setUser(senderId);
        connectionFactoryBean.setPassword(apiKey);
        connectionFactoryBean.setConnectionConfiguration(connectionConfiguration());
        return connectionFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

Service class:

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private XmppConnection xmppConnection;

}
```

Is that the right approach? How can I send an XMPP message to GCM? Should I use XmppConnection directly or some Spring messaging abstraction?

**UPDATE**

Created a MessageHandler and defined bean names.

```
@Bean(name = "xmppConnection")
public XmppConnectionFactoryBean xmppConnectionFactoryBean() {
    XmppConnectionFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean = new XmppConnectionFactoryBean();
    connectionFactoryBean.setUser(senderId);
    connectionFactoryBean.setPassword(apiKey);
    connectionFactoryBean.setConnectionConfiguration(connectionConfiguration());
    return connectionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(name = "gcmChannel")
public MessageChannel messageChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "gcmChannel")
public MessageHandler messageHandler() {
    return new ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler();
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("gcmChannel")
private MessageChannel messageChannel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it would be better to use a specific Spring Integration Adapter on the matter. It is `ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler`.

And we right now in the merging phase for the `Extensions` support for that adapter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1745. So, with the next Spring Integration 4.3 version you will have more GCM support there.

Right now as a workaround you have to create an XMPP message with GCM extension manually and send it to the channel for that `ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for your help. There is some way to create all the things needed without xml? In my service class I should use a MessageChannel instance?

Comment: M-m-m. Yes, you have to declare `@ServiceActivator` for the `ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler` and some `MessageChannel` bean to interact with that. I'm not sure why you need that `MyService` at all, when you can just get a gain from the `@MessagingGateway` feature. All that you can find in the Spring Integration Manual.

Comment: Ok. Take a look at answer update. Now I need to create an AbstractTransformer to transform a Spring message into a Smack message with gcm payload?

Comment: Config looks good, but don't forget to add `@EnableIntegration`. No, you don't need such a transformer. You should just provide `Smack message` as a `payload` to send. That can be as a param of your `@Gateway`.